# Undeleting a post with a negative score reduces reputation

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, deleted-posts, undelete

**Bug Recreation Steps:**

1. Delete a post that has a negative score
2. Watch your reputation points. They will remain the same, e.g. 13
3. Undelete your previous post
4. Wait for some time, say 5 minutes, and refresh your page and see you reputation lessen to 11. (as 13-2 = 11)

Answer (score 5):

No repro. I think you got downvoted in that time interval, which is the -2 you're describing.